# building a array with a counter

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to build a array whit a counter input. In this example `$j =3`.

What I want to do is adding to the array only the:

```
'name_'.$j => array(
    'required' => true),
```

and

```
'email_'.$j => array(
    'valcheck' => true,
    'required' => true)
```

until `$j` is met.

```
$j = '3';

$array = array(
    'titel' => array(
        'required' => true),
    'email' => array(
        'valcheck' => true,
        'required' => true),
    'name_'.$j => array(
        'required' => true),
    'email_'.$j => array(
        'valcheck' => true,
        'required' => true)
);

var_dump($array);
```

For example what I mean before as an output is:

```
array(6) { ["titel"]=> array(1) { 
    ["required"]=> bool(true) } 
["email"]=> array(2) { 
    ["valcheck"]=> bool(true) 
    ["required"]=> bool(true) } 
["naam"]=> array(1) { 
    ["required"]=> bool(true) } 
["datum"]=> array(1) { 
    ["required"]=> bool(true) } 
["name_1"]=> array(1) { 
    ["required"]=> bool(true) } 
["email_1"]=> array(2) { 
    ["valcheck"]=> bool(true) 
    ["required"]=> bool(true) } }
```

and afther :

```
array(10) { ["titel"]=> array(1) { 
    ["required"]=> bool(true) } 
["email"]=> array(2) { 
    ["valcheck"]=> bool(true) 
    ["required"]=> bool(true) } 
["naam"]=> array(1) { 
    ["required"]=> bool(true) } 
["datum"]=> array(1) { 
    ["required"]=> bool(true) } 
["name_1"]=> array(1) { 
    ["required"]=> bool(true) } 
["email_1"]=> array(2) { 
    ["valcheck"]=> bool(true) 
    ["required"]=> bool(true) } 
["name_2"]=> array(1) { 
    ["required"]=> bool(true) } 
["email_2"]=> array(2) { 
    ["valcheck"]=> bool(true) 
    ["required"]=> bool(true) } 
["name_3"]=> array(1) { 
    ["required"]=> bool(true) } 
["email_4"]=> array(2) { 
    ["valcheck"]=> bool(true) 
    ["required"]=> bool(true) } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a for loop.

```
$j = '3'; // define how many keys you want to define

for ($i=1; $i <= $j; $i++) {
    // Add new elements until you get to $j
    $array['name_'.$i] = array('required' => true);
    $array['email_'.$i] = array('valcheck' => true, 'required' => true);
}
```

Comment: thanks,
eventualy it helped.. what i was looking for is:
    if($j > 2){     
            for ($i=2; $i <= $j; $i++) {
                array_push($rules, array(
                    'name_'.$i => array(
                        'required' => true),
                    'email_'.$i => array(
                        'valcheck' => true,
                        'required' => true)
                    )
                );}
            }